# How to return both results and errors from a Repository in an implementation-independent way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, design-patterns, repository

I'm trying to implement a subset of the Repository pattern using Rails and am having some trouble understanding how to pass errors from a class or repository, back to the controller and then in to the view.

For instance, I have a class `DomainClass` which simply allows users to register a subdomain.  There are some rules there - it must be unique, must only contain letters and numbers - what have you.

When one or more model validations fails, I want to pass this value to the view somehow.  While passing those errors, I must also return "false" to the controller so it knows that whatever I've tried to do has failed.

This seems very simple.  What am I missing here?

```
Class - if this fails, I should pass the validation error to my controller.    

  # Create a domain ID and return the newly injected ID.do
  # If a new Domain ID couldn't be created for any reason,
  # return FALSE.
  def create_domain(domain_name)
    @domain.domain_name = domain_name
    if @domain.save
      return @domain.id
    else
      return false
    end
  end

Controller - From here, I should return the model's validation error to the view.

  # Try to save our user to the database
  if new_user = @domain.create_domain(domain_name)
    # Do things that are good.
  else
    # Return model's validation error here.
  end
```

Comment: Have I phrased this question poorly?  Can anyone help out a bit?

Comment: I don't see the value of the create_domain method. Couldn't you just call `@domain.update_attributes(domain_name)`? Also, since you have `@domain` in the controller, couldn't you just use `@domain.errors` in the view? Feel free to add to the question to clarify.

Comment: Fair question!  The `create_domain` method is included in a `create_account` repository along with a `create_user` function.  I could certainly add them directly in to the controller, but I want to extend a RESTful API later and it'll behoove me to keep that logic in a repository for that purpose.

Ultimately, I believe I can simply define a class variable, @errors, and populate it with any errors the model returns.  Then I can expose a function for returning the value of that @error variable to the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options for designing `create_domain` in a way that will still make sense when you reimplement it on top of some non-ActiveRecord store. Which one you would use depends on the situations in which you expect to use it.

1. Define a class to hold all of `create_domain`'s possible return values. This would be a start:

   ```
   class SaveResult < Struct.new :id, :errors
     def succeeded?
       errors.empty?
     end
   end
   ```

   In `create_domain`,

   ```
   return SaveResult.new *(
     if @domain.save
       @domain.id, []
     else
       nil, @domain.errors # this is an ActiveModel::Errors, but tell your callers it's a Hash
     end
   )
   ```

   Then a caller can do something like

   ```
   result = @domain.create_domain name
   if result.succeeded?
     # celebrate
   else
     # propagate errors to model
   end
   ```

   This design has the disadvantage that a caller has to remember to check whether there are errors. It would work well if most callers have to do something explicitly with the errors if there are any (as is the case above).
2. Define an exception to be raised when there are errors:

   ```
   class SaveError < Exception
     attr_accessor :errors # again, pretend it's just a hash

     def initialize(errors)
       self.errors = errors
     end

   end
   ```

   In `create_domain`,

   ```
   if @domain.save
     return @domain.id
   else
     raise SaveResult, @domain.errors
   emd
   ```

   Then a caller can do something like

   ```
   begin
     new_user_id = @domain.create_domain name
     # celebrate
   rescue SaveError => e
     # propagate errors to model
   end
   ```

   This design has the disadvantage that exception handling is a bit uglier to write than an `if`/`else`. It has the advantage that if you can just allow all such exceptions to propagate out of the caller and handle them in one place in `ActionController#rescue_from` or something like that, callers wouldn't need to write any error handling at all.

Comment: This is a great answer.  Thanks for going out of your way to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the title to try to bring out the essence of your question.